# Movie about a troubled man that takes his own life by slowly drowning

Tags: identify-this-movie

When I was younger I remember my dad watching what was either a movie or a TV show or a TV movie. It wasn't in Super high definition but it was in color and looked like it was made at least in the late 90's or early to mid 2000's. It felt so cinematic though. In the scene music plays as we see on a beautiful summer day a man in a house. Outside the girls (Either his or his friends daughters) are outside playing.

From what I remember the family was comfortable around him and thought him being around was completely normal, so he might be the dad. As he looks out he sees the girls playing in the sprinklers laughing and having fun. Giggling. Camera back to the man he looks and seems scared as he looks as he is remembering some kind of trauma. Close up on the Lawn Sprinklers and the water. And The Sound Da da da da da da da. Goes back to the girls then the man. Close up again on the sprinkler. Finally the man with tears in his eyes runs out and slow motion and grabs the girls and runs them into the house. As he screams in a scared manner. Get away, get away from it. (Or something to that extent)

The girls are frightened and crying. He screams in a scared way about them being safe. They cry. In slow motion he realizes what is happening sees the faces of the girls, and slowly snaps out of it. I think he then tries to apologize but the girls run away crying and sobbing. He then reacts in an extremely somber way as if something has just been taken away from him, He looks back at the water from the sprinklers with a look of fear in his eyes at the water.

Later in the movie, he is walking on the beach. I think somebody is trying to stop him from what he's about to do. He looks into the setting sun on the water. He confidently steps forward. He continues walking and does not stop. He takes steps into the water not stopping. Ankle deep, Shin deep, Knee deep he continues. Thigh deep , stomach deep chest deep. Always moving straight. Throughout this shot you see him from the back. His head slowly sinks as he continues forward. He doesn't come back up out of it.

It was such a sad scene. It seemed to me he had some sort of P.T.S.D. or fear of the water or something. He then takes his life for some reason confidently facing the very thing that he was so afraid of. It's uplifting that he's facing his worst tortured fears, it's sad that's the last thing he does in his life. So powerful! (Not that I would ever defend suicide, the tragedy is that he's killing himself in this way but it's so theatrical.)

I *really* ***really*** want to find out what this movie is! I want to figure out why the character committed suicide in what I believe is near the end of the movie. I can't get the images out of my mind. I want to see this movie again!

Comment: What's a TV movie?

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. **You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title**

Answer (score 7):

This movie must be K PAX (2001) by Iaian Softly starring Kevin Spacey and Jeff Bridges.

Please visit this link where it shows how Prot (Kevin Spacey) loses himself when the sprinklers turns on and runs to save the little girl. Rather stops her from going near the sprinklers.

Secondly the part where you are describing the man drowning himself is a scene where Jeff Bridges slowly understands how Prot tried to kill himself after finding his wife and daughters murdered after he comes back home from work.

I am searching for this suicide scene as well. I would edit and add it as soon as i get the link.

Its here at 1:20:23 where he tries drowning himself. Please watch these two and let us know if this was the movie you have watched.